# Passing variable arguments conditionally

Tags: objective-c, iphone, macos, conditional-statements, variadic-functions

In one of my iPhone application, I need to send the variable arguments to the action sheet conditionally. i.e

```
if(condition1)
    otherButtonTitles = @"Button1", @"Button2", nil
else
    otherButtonTitles = @"Button3", @"Button4", nil

UIActionSheet *mediaActionsSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle: nil
                                                             delegate: self
                                                    cancelButtonTitle: @"Cancel"
                                               destructiveButtonTitle: nil
                                                    otherButtonTitles: otherButtonTitles];
```

What is the syntax to do this? How should the data type for otherButtonTitles be defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. (Well, it's not impossible, but you don't want to do that.)

Just use

```
UIActionSheet *mediaActionsSheet=nil;
if(condition){
         mediaActionsSheet=[[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle: nil
                                                         delegate: self
                                                cancelButtonTitle: @"Cancel"
                                           destructiveButtonTitle: nil
                                                otherButtonTitles: @"button1",@"button2",nil];
}else{
         mediaActionsSheet=[[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle: nil
                                                         delegate: self
                                                cancelButtonTitle: @"Cancel"
                                           destructiveButtonTitle: nil
                                                otherButtonTitles: @"button2",@"button3",nil];
}
```

If you really want to construct a variable to hold variable number of arguments, start from [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdarg.h). But you don't really want to do that. I promise.

Answer (score 7):

```
UIActionSheet * mediaActionsSheet;
mediaActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle: nil
                                               delegate: self
                                      cancelButtonTitle: @"Cancel"
                                 destructiveButtonTitle: nil
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];


if(condition1){

    [mediaActionsSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Button1"];
    [mediaActionsSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Button2"];
}
else {

    [mediaActionsSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Button3"];
    [mediaActionsSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Button4"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you could simply create the action sheet within your condition.

```
UIActionSheet *mediaActionsSheet;
if(condition1)
    {
   mediaActionsSheet  = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle: nil
                                                             delegate: self
                                                    cancelButtonTitle: @"Cancel"
                                               destructiveButtonTitle: nil
                               otherButtonTitles:@"Button1", @"Button2", nil];
}

else


{
mediaActionsSheet  = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle: nil
                                                         delegate: self
                                                 cancelButtonTitle: @"Cancel"
                                              destructiveButtonTitle: nil
                                 otherButtonTitles:@"Button3", @"Button4", nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create 2 action sheets and can check in delegate right for suitable action..
why not 2 action sheets ?

something like :
- (void)actionSheetUIActionSheet *)modalView clickedButtonAtIndexNSInteger)buttonIndex
{
if( modalView==_firstActionSheetView )
{
}
else
{
}
}